# Selenium safari web driver doesn't launch safari browser using jenkins on Mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium, jenkins, safari

Safari browser test cases works fine when the ant script is triggered from terminal. However, same tests fails when the ant script is triggered from Jenkins. PS Error log mentioned. Please let me know your views.

**Error Log:**

```
   [testng] ===============================================

   [testng] Suite

   [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

   [testng] Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

   [testng] ===============================================


   [testng] Nov 18, 2014 6:29:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start

   [testng] INFO: Server started on port 6225

   [testng] The tests failed.
```

Thank you, Sande

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins executes without access to a display. It's a server application. That said Jenkins cannot start a safari browser. What you can do, however, is using PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) with GhostDriver (https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver). That's a browser that is pretty full featured but has no GUI at all. It renders everything to buffers. So you still can take screenshots and save those to files, but you can't see the browser window in real time.

PhantomJS uses WebKit as rendering engine, so there should be only little difference to Safari.

The setup in Java is very similar to SafariDriver:

```
File phantomBin = new File("lib/test/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs");
// http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", phantomBin.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("handlesAlerts", true);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Hey Hubert, 

I understood that Jenkins is a server program which doesn't have privileges to launch Safari on MAC. Will consider your approach as a workaround for now.  
Thank you, Sandeep